# why when i use setRowData it show this kind of issue (not read properties of undefined (reading 'replace') )

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

```
            this.wireStatus.push(this.wireStatus2);
            this.grid.setRowData(this.wireStatus2['status'], this.wireStatus2);
```

Expected to change the status to change from On to off and off to On when triggered

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to inform you that the setRowData method is used to change the row data only in UI, it does not affect the grid’s dataSource. So, if the grid get refreshed it rendered with old data and does not retain the modified data. This is the behavior of setRowData method.

setRowData: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/grid/#setrowdata

I have prepared a sample and tried to reproduce your reported problem at our end, but it was unsuccessful. Please refer the below code example and sample for more information.

click(args) {

```
    this.obj = {OrderID: 10248, CustomerID: 'Changed', Freight: 22, ShipCountry: 'France'};

    this.getPrimarykeyValue = this.grid.dataSource[0][this.grid.getPrimaryKeyFieldNames()[0]];

    this.grid.setRowData(this.getPrimarykeyValue, this.obj);

}
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zi2sw1?file=src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Error you are seeing is saying you are trying to access `wireStatus2` property which is not defined. Make sure to define before accessing and also check `grid` is defined before calling `setRowData()`. You can do it as following:

```
this.wireStatus2 = this.wireStatus2 || {};
this.wireStatus2.status = this.wireStatus2.status === "On" ? "Off" : "On";

if (this.grid) {
  this.grid.setRowData([this.wireStatus2]);
}
```